# How to redirect to Login page from an Ajax postback?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I work on an MVC 3 application. My cshtml page looks like this:

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("Filter", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "div_GridPlaceholder")
{
...some HTML
<input id="btn_Filter" type='submit' ... />
}

<div id="div_GridPlaceholder">...</div>
```

The Filter ( ) action method marked with the Authorize attribute returns some string at the moment. Everything works fine but when the forms authentication ticket expires and I hit the btn_Filter button, my Login page gets rendered in the div_GridPlaceholder which is pretty strange. I would like to have the see the Login page rendered on the whole page instead of inside that div. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you have it return a special string that tells you if the user's ticket is expired and redirect from this page if you get that value?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Logon` action you could append a custom response HTTP header:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    Response.AppendHeader("X-LOGON", "true");
    return View();
}
```

and then subscribe for the complete event and test for the presence of this header and act accordingly:

```
$(function () {
    $('#div_GridPlaceholder').ajaxComplete(function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {
        if (XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('X-LOGON') == 'true') {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account")';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your approach but the XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('X-LOGON') returns null every time.